# React, Jest and Enzyme configuration

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I have a problem with `react`, `jest` and `enzyme` configuration.
So basically I have installed dependencies like `jest`, `jest-cli`, `babel-jest`, `enzyme` and `enzyme-adapter-react-16`. I also have `setupTest.js` which looks like this:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

But I don't know why I am still getting an error `Unexpected token import` because of this line: `import { configure } from 'enzyme'`

Any solutions ?

Comment: your configurations seems right but  the way you run tests seems to have issue

Comment: I run them with `npm test` and my script looks like `"test": "jest"`

Comment: are you using create react app ?

Answer (score -1):

Hack around this, I formatted the code to:

```
const Enzyme = require('enzyme');
const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16');
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```